# MySQL se apaga solo en XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Cada vez que intento iniciar mysql en xampp, luego de mantenerse dos o tres segundos encendidos se apaga, no logro encontrar el error ya que no tengo ningun proceso a la vista encendido de sql, comparto la imagen del error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, por favor incluye los logs que aparecen en el botón logs y mylql_error.log

Comment: ¿Tenés instalado MySQL Workbench? Si llegaste a conectarte a MySQL desde allí (o de igual manera si no lo tenés instalado), ¿te fijaste que el puerto efectivamente esté liberado antes de conectarte vía XAMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP ha tenido ese problema por mucho tiempo y no parece que haya una solución cercana (de hecho, es una de las principales razones por las cuales dejé de usar xampp). Hay dos posibles soluciones:

Solucion 1:

- En la carpeta xampp/mysql renombrar el folder 'data' a 'data.old'
- Renombrar el folder 'backup' a 'data'
- Del folder 'data.old' copiar las bases de datos (excepto information_schema, mysql y phpmyadmin) hacia el folder 'data' (que antes era 'backup')
- Del folder 'data.old' copiar el archivo 'ibdata1' hacia 'data',
  sobrescribiendo el archivo que se encuentra allí.
- Iniciar MySQL y reparar las tablas dentro de la base de datos 'mysql'

Solución 2:

- agregar 'skip-grant-tables' a 'xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini' justo después de la etiqueta [mysqld], entonces phpmyadmin se iniciará sin chequeos.
- en la base de datos llamada 'mysql' reparar la tabla 'db' (de la misma forma que se elimina una tabla, existe la opción 'reparar tabla')
- borrar la opción 'skip-grant-tables' de 'xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini'
- reiniciar MySQL